# How to calculate weights based on targets in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas and stuck on calculating weights based on demographic targets.

Here are the counts from my dataset:

```
group = df.groupby('GENDR')['Age_cat'].value_counts(sort=False)

GENDR  Age_cat 
1  18 to 24    19
   25 to 34    24
   35 to 44    25
   45 to 54    23
   55 to 64    16
   65+         64
2  18 to 24    14
   25 to 34    19
   35 to 44    24
   45 to 54    25
   55 to 64    17
   65+         51
Name: Age_cat, dtype: int64
```

And here are my weighting targets which I loaded into a separate dataframe.

```
wt = wt.unstack()
wt

Male0    0.058783
    1    0.080367
    2    0.082995
    3    0.098865
    4    0.080890
    5    0.082726
Fema0    0.056920
    1    0.082637
    2    0.086267
    3    0.101823
    4    0.084402
    5    0.103325
dtype: float64
```

So how do I put this all together? I'd want to create a weight value for each case that would result in the desired proportions.

Comment: Show us what the final result ought to look like including the calculation that was made.

Comment: okay I don't know how, but i want to divide the target proportions by the actual proportions for each group, and assign the result to every case in that group.  So I need to access the result of the first groupby (as a %, so normalize=True) I suppose. There would be a new column that would be 1 of 10 possible weight values.

Comment: Sorry I should have made clear that the wt dataframe is in the order I want (i.e. 0 is 18-24 Target, 1 is 25 to 24, etc. . . )